# Break for loop while not stopping the while loop

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

Ok I dont know how to ask this question properly but here is what I am trying to do:

```
#connect to db and stuff
check_against = [] #list of strings
while row is not None:
  if row == None:
    break
  for i in range(0,len(row)):
    x = row[i]
    try:
      print str(x)
    except:
      pass
    for z in check_against:
      if z == x:
        #change alternate_id
    if x == "":
      # Change insert_into and stuff
      if alternate_id != 0:
        for x in range(len(insert_into)):  #Do SQL things
          print "updating" + str(alternate_id)
          sql = """UPDATE `table` SET `%s` = '%s' WHERE `table`.`id` = %s""" % (insert_into[x],check_against[x],str(alternate_id))
      try:
         cursor.execute(sql)
         db.commit()
      except:
         db.rollback()
      break #This break breaks the while loop
  row = cursor.fetchone()
```

How can I make the break not break the while loop but break the for loop? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's exactly what your code already does... In fact you can't leave the `while`, because `x` never changes inside it.

Comment: Am I doing it wrong then? When I use this in real code it breaks the while loop.

Comment: @Tygran,  could you provide all the code? because it looks like current implementation breaks the `for` loop, as you want

Comment: Then give a [mcve] that actually recreates the issue (**not** *"all the code"*), because that one doesn't.

Comment: I can try making the snippet more like real code cause real code is really long. Give me a minute.

Comment: Now the code makes even less sense.

Comment: Why do you do things like check for `None` and then immediately check again, and put a simple `print` in a `try` block?

Comment: I am reading sql until I get a empty line (I hope that isnt wrong when it works), the try print thing is simplified too, sorry I didnt want to paste 100 lines. I dont want to be an asshole but I dont think stuff like that doesnt matter to the problem.

Comment: Why do you think that that specific `break` breaks out of the `while` loop? There's nothing you've shown that indicates that the `while` loop doesn't exit for another reason.

Comment: Because when I run the code it stops after printing the line with "updating" in it. Just forget this question, I will try making a new one properly formated and with a better cody snippet. I am sorry for the problems I gave you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you don't need this part:

```
while row is not None:
    if row == None:
        break
```

this part doesn't have any sense, because if the row is None the `while` loop will stop, because of condition `while row is not None`, please remove :

```
if row == None:
    break
```

you don't need this code.

the second part:

if a `break` breaks your `while` loop, please format your code in a right way, because current code looks strange

Comment: I think I have figured it out. The break doesnt break the while loop but the problem was that I executed the sql with the same cursor as I was getting the lines from. Thanks for your help. I am dumb.

Comment: you're welcome! The question was about breaking a while loop, I told how to resolve this question